# Why Euclidean space isn't (Gromov) Hyperbolic?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm trying to understand why the hyperbolic plane is Gromov Hyperbolic while the Euclidean plane isn't. I guess that there is connection to the fact that every similar triangles in $\mathbb{H}^2$ are congruence triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What's the thinness constant for an equilateral triangle of side length 1,000,000,000,000,000?

Comment: Thank you :) :)